# Getting radio buttons to realign at a smaller resolution

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to get these radio buttons and text box to move into a vertical line when the page is reduced to a smaller size (<600). Right now they are being displayed horizontally.

```html
<div >
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-8" style="width:100%">
                <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Male" @required>
                <label for="MALE">Male</label>

                <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Female">
                <label for="FEMALE">Female</label>

                <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Prefer not to say">
                <label for="PREFERNOTTOSAY"> Prefer not to say </label>

                <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Other">
                <label for="OTHER"> Other (please specify) </label>

                <input type="text" class="form-control c-form__input" value="">
            </div>
</div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a media query here, when the screen size gets below 600 make your input fields 100% width

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  input {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-8" style="width:100%">
    <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Male" @required>
    <label for="MALE">Male</label>

    <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Female">
    <label for="FEMALE">Female</label>

    <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Prefer not to say">
    <label for="PREFERNOTTOSAY"> Prefer not to say </label>

    <input type="radio" class="gender" value="Other">
    <label for="OTHER"> Other (please specify) </label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control c-form__input" value="">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this fiddle I have just created:
https://jsfiddle.net/Ghazi360/rz0p3dae/3/

What have I done?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  input {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

It will work perfectly by adding this media query to resize your input fields to 100% when screen size is less than 600px.